# Amazon SES Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied "

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm Trying to send email in Laravel using Amazon SES. Now I'm getting this error.

> Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1
> Relaying denied "

This is My ENV file Config File:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST="ses-smtp-user.20210628-181755"
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=justshamsulalom@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

This is Mail:

```
'mailers' => [
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null,
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'transport' => 'ses',
    ],
]
```

How Can I solve this issue?

Comment: issue in your email server kindly check settings of that email  some restriction on your email so that error generates .

Comment: Connection to tcp://email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:465 Timed Out